# How to change text in HTML Global with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**How to Replacing a part of a string in HTML Global with javascript ?**

Example :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://dr1.masbro.id/js2.js'></script>
```

I Need to change dr1 to dr2,

After :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://dr2.masbro.id/js2.js'></script>
```

Comment: What have you tried ? At least that could make one understand the question...

Comment: Note: you don't need `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?  Reading a property from an element?  Replacing a part of a string?  Writing a property to an element?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is replace the part of the value of `src`:

```
<script src='http://dr1.masbro.id/js2.js' id="myscript"></script>

let myscript = document.getElementById('myscript');
myscript.src = myscript.src.replace('dr1', 'dr2');
```

Note though, that this will not remove anything from `http://dr1.masbro.id/js2.js` from your current js context. The same thing could be achieved by simply loading `http://dr2.masbro.id/js2.js` into the DOM, or just having both in script tags from the beginning.

Comment: just change this string sir..
i not have edit this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to scripts only by this way

```
document.scripts
```

it will return scripts in array.

```
document.scripts[0].outerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://dr2.masbro.id/js2.js'></script>"
```

Comment: You can access to scripts only by this way

    document.scripts

it will return scripts in array.

    document.scripts[0].outerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://dr2.masbro.id/js2.js'></script>"

but i not edit this script, if i have to edit i can edit with PHP.
now just javascript helped me..

Answer (score 0):

**

```html
<p>Jeds Page</p>
<input type="text" id="jed" value="text here"/>
```

**

Comment: It seems like this does not answer the question. Please expand it to include what is missing, or delete your answer.